# Checking write permissions on parent directory

Tags: bash, directory, parent

I have a slight problem.Basically the problem is trivial, but my solution doesn't seem to work.

The script that I've came up with, goes something like that:

1. You pass the directory as a $1 parameter. For instance: ./script.sh /Desktop/folder1/folder1submap/myfolder
2. If the structure /folder1/folder1submap/myfolder doesn't exist I must create it. No problems here, but problem arises because I must first check if the location is writable. I'm testing this with [ -w "target" ] command but it doesn't work because -w is always false if folder doesn't exist. And in my case, it doesn't.

   Solution: Yes I could check the parent folder if it's writable but you cannot know if  youre going to get for instance: /Desktop/folder1  or something like this /Desktop/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/folder5/ so i can't check the parent folder for rights as easily as I want. To be precise, I cannot know which directory is parent directory if I get arbitrary long path from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the `dirname` command:

```
if [ ! -d "$1" ] && [ -w "$(dirname $1)" ]; then 
    mkdir "$1"
fi
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work. $1 is in no case a symlink.

Comment: Can you be more specific? `$1/..` is a perfectly valid path (assuming `$1` is a directory, and not a file), and you should be able to test if it is writable just like any other path.

Comment: Yes I can offcourse. I've tested it with:

if [ -w "/home/username/Desktop/folder"]

Here I get an true evaluation which is as expected.(folder is a directory that exist on my Desktop)

if [ -w "/home/username/Desktop/folder2/.."]

Here I get an false evaluation and folder2 doesn't exist on my Desktop!

Comment: That's what I get for being fancy. `..` of course requires `$1` to exist, since it is an actual directory entry. `dirname` treats `$1` as a string, so should work when `$1` does not exist as a directory. Sorry about that.